# Need some help for X pages Set Authenticate access

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

i have created a webpage using xpages. I not sure how to use Access control rules to force user to go login page and check for "address book" account.

Below will be the sample page i created using xpages.

1. Submit button to check address book whether this person is exist or not
   [image: Submit]
2. Anonymous to request for an email address for their address book. This one will by pass the validation and go to the request page but only "Anonymous can access".
   [image: Apply]
3. Login...Go to "Approved page", but before that, user need to go to server login screen to login his user account.[image: Login1]
   [image: server login]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lock down the database to enforce the authentication access:

- Edit the ACL (File - Application - Access Control) and set access for Anonymous to "No Access" but check "Read Public Documents"
- Now you would need to authenticate for **every** page (which is not what you want), so you edit xpage properties and check "Available for public access Users" property for all pages a user shall be able to access unauthenticated
- You might need to flag a few additional design elements too ([check the official details](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_Public_Access_Support))
- While you are on it: [customise your login page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_customizingthehtmlloginform_t.html) in domcfg.nsf

More on ACL basics: https://www.wissel.net/blog/2010/09/access-control-in-domino-the-basics.html

If your struggle, give me a call (the NRIC in the screenshot suggest you are in Singapore like me)

Comment: Thanks. I try the one you suggest, it working but it take time to configure all form that related.So i use another way "ACL"entry(role) to logon page to control it. which i found on internet sources. http://www.xpagetips.com/2012/08/remember-you-can-use-xpage-acl-entries.html

Comment: That works too. Just make sure your security matches business requirements. A third option is to split the app into 2 databases: the open front-end and the access controlled backend. That also ensures your data's safety. Keep in mind one can bypass XPages when they know/guess your view names and use ?ReadViewEntries to see data